# Scraping a POST-request AJAX web page with watir-webdriver (or any other way in Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, web-scraping, watir-webdriver, http-post

I'm trying to get arrest data from the police blotter of the [Palm Beach County Sheriff's Office.](http://www.pbso.org/index.cfm?fa=blotter)

I've limited my search to the city of West Palm Beach, going back as far as the data goes (Oct. 31, 1974).

I'm using FireFox.

When I get the results, I open up FireBug, check the HTML tab, and I can see the info I want from the page (i.e., arrested person's name, arrest address, charges, etc.).

I checked the Net>>XHR>>Post tab to find the POST request parameters, but putting that into my code does nothing. It probably doesn't help that I'm a complete newbie to watir-webdriver.

Here's my code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'http://www.pbso.org/index.cfm?fa=blotter'
b.text_field(:name => 'start_date').set '01/01/1900'
b.text_field(:name => 'city_name').set 'West Palm Beach'
b.button(:name => 'process').click
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the response page HTML (i.e., the HTML that contains the name, address, crime, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That one doesn't look so bad, I would use mechanize instead:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
form = agent.get('http://www.pbso.org/index.cfm?fa=blotter').forms[0]
form['captcha_id'] = -1

# page 1 of results
page = form.submit

# page 2 of results
form['fromrec'] = form['fromrec'].to_i + 5
page = form.submit
```

The problem with watir-webdriver and ajax updated results is the errors you will get when a dom element that was there one moment is suddenly gone

Comment: In this case, am I right in guessing that the DOM elements are the tables with the arrest info? Also, I wonder if it would really be a concern with the blotter, since new bookings are added to the last pages, rather than the first.

Comment: As for the code, I'm also new to the mechanize gem (I installed both watir-webdriver and mechanize yesterday while trying to scrape). Can you please tell me what the 'forms[0]' part in line 3 refers to? As for line 4, I'm guessing that 'captcha_id' refers to one of the POST requests on the blotter results. I'm guessing it's necessary so that 'form.submit' submits the POST request with 'captcha_id' set to -1? And lastly, do you know how I can see the results? Using 'puts page' or 'pp page' doesn't give what I'm looking for. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: forms[0] just means the first form on the page. You can see the html with page.body or search by xpath or css selectors with for example page.search('.contentTxt')

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the HTML of the page, you can do:

```
puts b.html
```

Or to limit it to the HTML of the table containing the data:

```
puts b.table(:class, 'contentTxt').html
```

Though you would have to loop through all the pages of results. So something like this, noting that you need to wait until the results appear after each navigation.

```
at_end = false
begin
  #Wait until the results appear
  b.table(:class, 'contentTxt').wait_until_present

  #Output the results
  puts b.table(:class, 'contentTxt').html

  #Go to next page if it exists
  if b.link(:text => /Next/, :class => 'contentTxt').exists?
    b.link(:text => /Next/, :class => 'contentTxt').click
  else 
    at_end = true
  end
end until at_end
```

Comment: This code definitely seems to work fine in getting the HTML I want, though I wonder what you think of puardario's comment on the possibility of AJAX updates removing a DOM element during scraping.

Comment: While it is an interesting point and technically possible, I have not personally run into that issue before. Perhaps it would occur when working with a page that continually updates with real time data, like an auction page. In your current scenario, I do not think it is something to worry about (ie the page seems static). However, you do have to ensure you wait for the page to finish loading (hence the `wait_until_present`).

Comment: I see. This code works, though it's a bit slower than pguardiario's. That said, I'd love to be able to 'check' multiple answers, and I thank you for helping me learn how to use watir-webdriver better.